# Disable auto update on Edge browser installed on windows server 2019

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-server-2019

I am trying to disable the auto update on edge browser to freeze version 85.x.x(chromium based) installed on windows server 2019 without any luck. Can someone please help me with the exact working steps?

I would also appreciate any other ideas to freeze the version on edge browser.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you refer to the steps below that may help you to disable auto-update for the MS Edge Chromium browser.

1. Download the **Edge policy template** from [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download) link.
2. Install the policy template by referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge#1-download-and-install-the-microsoft-edge-administrative-template) link.
3. Open the **Local Group Policy editor**.
4. Browse to the path below.

> Computer configuration -> Administrative templates -> Microsoft Edge
> update -> Applications

5. Find and double click on [Update policy override default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-update-policies#update-policy-override-default) policy.
6. Click on the **Enabled** radio button and select **Updates disabled** option from the dropdown (you can select the update option that is suitable for your requirements).

[image]

7. click on the **Apply** button and then click on the **OK** button.

Comment: Can you please explain what all this does and why so many different downloads are necessary? Also, in the page that you linked (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download) I am asked to select a build of Edge before I can download the group policy file. I think it's not adequate to point reader to a page where he has to select something which is not clear and also not clear what it's for.